# Java 6 converting utf8 to iso88591 charset and ignoring unmappable characters

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

I have written the following function which gets rid of characters in a string that can't be represented in iso88591:

```
public static String convert(String str) {
    if (str.length()==0) return str;
    str = str.replace("–","-");
    str = str.replace("“","\"");
    str = str.replace("”","\"");
    return new String(str.getBytes(),iso88591charset);
}
```

My problem is this doesn't have the behavior I require.
When it comes across a character that has no representation it is converted to multiple bytes. I want that character to be simply omitted from the result.

I would also like to somehow not have to have all those replace commands.

I have been researching charsetEnocder. It has methods like:

```
CharsetEncoder encoder = iso88591charset.newEncoder();
encoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
encoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
```

which seem to be what I want, but I have failed to even write a function that mimics what I already have using charset encoder yet alone get to set those options.

Also I am restricted to Java 6 :(

Update:
I came up with a nasty solution for this, but there must be a better way to do it:

```
public static String convert(String str) {
    if (str.length()==0) return str;
    str = str.replace("–","-");
    str = str.replace("“","\"");
    str = str.replace("”","\"");
    String str2 = "";
    for (int c=0;c<str.length();c++) {
        String cur = (new Character(str.charAt(c))).toString();
        if (cur.equals(new String(cur.getBytes(),iso88591charset))) str2 += cur;
    }
    return new String(str2.getBytes(),iso88591charset);
}
```

Comment: To map to ISO-8859-1 just ignore all characters with a numeric value >= 256. This will however not cover the replacements you made.

Comment: To represent text in the ISO 8859-1 encoding, you have to use a data type that is not specifically designed for UTF-16, like `String`, `Character` and `char` are. How about `byte[]`?

Comment: And, given that `String`, `Character` and `char` are for UTF-16, how does UTF-8 come into the question? Perhaps that's a detail about the source of the text. It shouldn't matter once you have a `String`.

Comment: The source of the text is utf-8 and it needs to be passed to a old function not controlled by me which will fall if I pass it anything that can't be represented in iso88591.

Comment: Okay, UTF-16 (`String`) to UTF-16 (`String`) with transliteration and filtering.  There are a few ways to write the filtering but all would be similar to @SubOptimal's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48464440/2226988). Unicode was designed with ISO 8859-1 in mind: The first 256 codepoints are the same. So, in UTF-16, <= '\u00ff', or in Unicode blocks [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) or C1 Controls and Latin-1 Supplement. See [Character.UnicodeBlock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.htm)

Answer (score 1):

One possibile way could be

```
// U+2126 - omega sign
// U+2013 - en dash
// U+201c - left double quotation mark
// U+201d - right double quotation mark
String str = "\u2126\u2013\u201c\u201d";
System.out.println("original = " + str);
str = str.replace("–", "-");
str = str.replace("“", "\"");
str = str.replace("”", "\"");
System.out.println("replaced = " + str);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (c <= '\u00ff') {
        sb.append(c);
    }
}
System.out.println("stripped = " + sb);
```

output

```
original = Ω–“”
replaced = Ω-""
stripped = -""
```

Comment: @Henry You're right. My mistake. Fixed it in the answer.